# Core Data is gone after the crash

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode7

I'm using Core Data in my iOS app.  I save the data and retrieve the data while the app is running and it works fine.  I also can retrieve the saved data when I exit the app and restart it, no problem.  But if I start my app on my device - an iPhone 6 - that is connected to the computer using the debugger in Xcode 7.2 and then disconnect my device while the app is still running, the app crashes.  When I start the app again all the Core Data is gone.  Is there an explanation for this?  Is there anything I can do to gather more data from the device.  No info is reported at the time of crash in the debugger.  Thanks!

Comment: A log of the crash or error presented would be advisable. Is the debugger crashing, or the app?

Comment: The app crashes, not the debugger.  The debugger doesn't show anything about the crash.  I don't know if there's any crash report on the device, and if there's such a report how to get it.  I launched the app using the debugger and I haven't used archiving.

Comment: When do you save your data? Are you sure that you're doing that when you cause the app to crash like this?

Comment: I save the data throughout the app, when the app is terminated and when it's going to the background.  As I said when the app is not crashed, everything works fine.  Maybe one good question is why the app crashes when I remove the device.

Comment: Where specifically in your app are you calling save on your Core Data?

Comment: I have written a class that manages Core Data.  In that class I have a method that saves the data.  Throughout the app when I change the data I call this method to save it for me.  The code is huge otherwise I would have posted it here.  It works fine, the evidence is that when I am not disconnecting the device from Xcode when the app is running so that I don't get the crash, the data is fine in the next start.

Comment: Why does Xcode crash under this circumstances?